# Migrate data from solr 1.4 to 7.0.1

Tags: search, indexing, solr

Is there any direct, or easy way to migrate solr from version 1.4 to 7.0.1 ? is there any guide ?
I have tried o do backup, replication, copying the files, but still not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reindex, reindex. However, there's an [IndexUpgrader bundled with each version of Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0//core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexUpgrader.html) that upgrades the index (and its usually done automagically for you) from a previous version, but as time goes on, support for older formats is deprecated.

To go from 1.4 you'll first have to get to 4.x - which probably involves going to 3.x first, then to 4 (but check - 4.x miiight be able to ready 1.4 files).

When you get to 4, you can use jan's excellent [upgradeindex](https://github.com/cominvent/solr-tools/tree/master/upgradeindex) script, which downloads the relevant 5 and 6 versions and upgrades the index for you so it's ready for 7.x.

But remember that there's more to each upgrade of Solr than just the index version.

Comment: Thanks. i already have performed index upgrade, so what else is requied?

Comment: As Persimmonium mentions below, you'll have to map the field types to the current schema types - if possible. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: here is another question with error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714965/after-solr-upgrade-from-1-4-to-7-0-1-getting-unknown-field-error

Answer (score 3):

Solr had always quite good compat against at least the previous version (even previous-1 version), so I think migrating step by step (1.4->3, 3->4...) should be totally doable and will work.

Now, that does mean:

- you have to look at every versions docs to see how to upgrade from previous one
- it is going to be much much much simpler to just reindex in 7.x
- you will have to tweak config files lots of times to account for deprecated types etc

Bottomline, if you have source data, reindex, without a doubt. If that is impossible, you can do it, it's just going to be a lot of (boring) work.

Answer (score 2):

I would guess not.  The differences in index etc... are too great.

My recommendation (if it's possible) is to re-gather your data from wherever you got it (Database or whatever) and submit it to Solr 7.x for re-indexing.

If you can't do that (from a database or something)...  If, in other words, SOLR itself is the "authoritative source" for the data, it's going to be tricky...  I haven't tried to solve that problem myself, but I'd consider finding a way to get the data out in some kind of raw form to be submitted to SOLR 7.x for indexing.

Trying to migrate your way - step by step - from 1.4 to 7.x is going to be incredibly difficult...  possibly not do-able.

Consider posting your question to the SOLR user group too...  Look on the Solr site for how to sign up.

Comment: Agreed, but about getting the data out, the non-stored fields will be lost.